# Downloading jmeter with all the plugins (or just extra-with-libs which has redis dataset) in a tar file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running an EC2 instance and I want to install jmeter on it. I am only finding the source tar files of jmeter but want the extra plugins as well. Wanted to know how to install them as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check link, it has the details. 
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/

Comment: Thanks! I had already went through it but still 'redis' option doesn't show up in the GUI. Will post in the google group for the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download JMeter and it's plugins separately.
You can find http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi binaries here. Depending on the operating system download tgz or zip.

Download http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/ from here and unzip them and copy them to /lib/ext folder of JMeter folder.

This should be enough to set up the system.